# MySql User Input If Empty = '00' ELEIF single digit add a zero prior

Tags: php, mysql, user-input

I have a user input that if they leave it blank it will POST '00' else it POSTS whatever they entered.  I need to set it up as if blank post '00' elseif user enters single digit it will append a '0' at the beginning.  I already have the database set up as an INT with ZEROFILL so that it will hold the zero.  My Code as of now is

```
        if (empty($_POST['num'][$i]))
        { $_POST['num'][$i] = '00';}
```

and to insert it into the table I run

```
        $datanum = "Insert into Data (num) VALUES ('" . $_POST['num'][$i] . "')";
```

Comment: use str_pad function to add zero.

Comment: I looked at str_pad_left but didn't see a way to tie it into the code

Answer (score 0):

Use str_pad function

```
$_POST['num'][$i] = str_pad(trim($_POST['num'][$i]), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Execute the code here
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be5f1e4888fefd5522a9e83274cc587c878e1f8c